# Pandas computed column based on previous rows conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```py
                       date_open               date_closed       rate
id                                                                   
284113 2020-02-21 08:47:00+00:00 2020-03-04 08:55:28+00:00  11.588895
284114 2020-02-21 08:47:05+00:00 2020-03-04 08:55:22+00:00  11.588895
284115 2020-02-21 08:47:09+00:00 2020-03-04 08:55:13+00:00  11.588895
284116 2020-02-21 08:47:13+00:00 2020-03-04 08:55:07+00:00  11.559593
284117 2020-02-21 08:47:17+00:00 2020-03-04 08:53:11+00:00  11.530291
                          ...                       ...        ...
373069 2020-04-22 16:31:30+00:00 2020-04-30 17:25:55+00:00   3.481590
373070 2020-04-22 16:31:35+00:00 2020-04-30 17:25:23+00:00   3.510351
373071 2020-04-22 16:31:40+00:00 2020-04-30 17:24:25+00:00   3.529525
381966 2020-04-30 17:26:11+00:00 2020-04-30 17:28:43+00:00  -0.162813
381969 2020-04-30 17:26:49+00:00 2020-04-30 17:28:30+00:00  -0.181308
[131 rows x 3 columns]
```

I'd like to add column, called `efficiency`.

Every row should have `efficiency` computed as the sum of `rate`s > 0 divided by the sum of `rate`s <= 0 of the rows that have `date_closed` <= `date_open` of the current row.

In python code (supposing a list of dicts instead of a dataframe) I would achieve that result like this:

```py
for element in list_of_dicts:
   positive_rates = sum(list(filter(lambda x: x['rate'] > 0 and x['date_closed'] < element['date_open'], list_of_dicts)))
   negative_rates = sum(list(filter(lambda x: x['rate'] < 0 and x['date_closed'] < element['date_open'], list_of_dicts)))
   element['efficiency'] = postitive_rates / negative_rates
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look at np.where()

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to solve this issue one is better in terms of speed and the other in terms of memory.

The first: create a new column `group`, do an outer `merge`, filter using a `mask`, group by `id`, apply a lambda function to the grouped dataframe, and assign the results:

```
df['group'] = 1
df_merge = df.reset_index().merge(df[['date_closed', 'rate', 'group']],
                                  how='outer', on='group')

mask = df_merge['date_open'] >= df_merge['date_closed_y']

results = df_merge[mask].groupby('id')
          .apply(lambda df: df[df.rate_y > 0].rate_y.sum() /
                df[df.rate_y <= 0].rate_y.sum())

df['efficiency'] = results
```

The second: Simply `apply` function to each row:

```
df['efficiency'] = df.apply(lambda x:
     df[(df.date_closed <= x.date_open) & (df.rate > 0)].rate.sum()
     / df[(df.date_closed <= x.date_open) & (df.rate <= 0)].rate.sum(), axis=1)
```